# xsl:fo - I want to have 2 dynamical contents in flow region-body

Tags: xslt

I whant to have advertising on all the left page (different on all left page and based on page-number if possible) and dynamic content on all the right page from an xml feed

When I declare a fo:flow flow-name="body-left" and fo:flow flow-name="body-right" I get an error (only one flow possible)
ans I can't get the value of page-number as variable

I develop with saxon 9.3 xsl 2.0

Thanks for help

Bilsi